# Display empty grid message on igheirarchical grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, infragistics

As per the post in the forum

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/93487.aspx

I want to display the same no data found message in igHeirarchical grid but dont find any events to which i can write the function to do the same.

Comment: Provide a code example in your question, instead of linking to the forum thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rowsRendered` event for this:

```
$("#gridid").igHierarchicalGrid({
    ...
    rowsRendered: function (event, ui) {
        var hasData = ui.owner.options.dataSource.root().data().length;
        if (!hasData) {
            // render empty data message
        }
    }
});
```